# Blurred text/desktop

Tags: linux, windows-10, intel-graphics

I'm having a problem with my Linux (*and windows desktops*). On windows my screen gets blurred after a bit of usage and newly opened apps get this immediately too.

I believe this has started only since I started using Windows 10 and the issue was not on the previous versions of Windows (7, 8, 8.1) for me. On linux, this usually happens after waking from hibernation. 
The desktop is also blurred. Reloading the window manager doesn't change anything.

Sometimes changing the zoom helps for firefox. Would anyone know how to resolve this? I don't know what information would help in solving this problem, can someone tell me what info to add here? This is a 2009 Thinkpad, `Lenovo Thinkpad T500` with product `id 2242-CTO`. I have integrated intel graphics.

Going by @alljamin's link, the reason may be that I have two memory sticks, one each of 2GB and 1GB.
 
We don't know the root problem (whether it's two sticks or a 1GB stick or a mismatch)

[image: Blurry Text in application]

Comment: Did windows 10 use your graphics driver or install a Generic one? which Linux may also be pulling from?

Comment: Check your ``Device manager`` for any missing driver installed. You also might want to look into [this](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3519/t/19251198) as it is the similar issue with ``Intel GM45`` family graphic cards.

Comment: If it happens on both Windows and Linux (not running in a VM), chances aren't that low that it might actually be some hardware problem.

Comment: Looks like my memory being 3gb is the reason, going by @alljamin 's link.

Comment: While i assume as well a hardware issue like Mario, please check if the cable connecting external display and gfx-card is properly connected on both sides. If its the laptop internal screen its getting ugly at this point ;)

Comment: @dufte It *is* the laptop screen. Its an old computer, yes, if that's what you meant by ugly :)

Comment: You could try connecting an external monitor if you have one - do you have the same issue on the external monitor ?

Comment: @JonasCz sorry no external monitor..